# How to remember user name and password on website that prevent browsers from doing so

Tags: browser, autocomplete, password-management

The example website is manuscript central:
eg: http://mc.manuscriptcentral.com/ele

It does not appear to use the html autocomplete blocking tag.

Comment: Ignore my answer for the moment, I didn't see the autocomplete tag note

Comment: Ok, answer updated for this scenario

Comment: Though I was using Safari, I did find this for chrome which works: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ecpgkdflcnofdbbkiggklcfmgbnbabhh

Comment: This seems to be a Safari solution, though it has yet to work for me:  http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2010/06/10/safari-extension-autocomplete/

Comment: @EtienneLow-Décarie the solution you link to *also* relies on the presence of 'autocomplete' in the html (in order to be able to change it to xutocomplete), and you said you can't find the 'autocomplete' element in the page.  So, exactly how does the solution you found work, if Paul's solution does not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't stated which browser you are using, but this is achievable using [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) user scripts, which are available for a number of [browsers](http://userscripts.org/about/installing).

Preventing the autocompletion of fields and saving passwords is achieved using the `autocomplete="no"` attribute on form elements.   [This](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/588) [greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) script removes the attribute from form fields allowing them to be saved.

In this case however, while a form is used to capture the userid and password, it the form is never submitted, and so the form data is never prompted to be saved.  Instead it uses javascript to gather the entries and do an ajax call to authenticate.

One work around (just tested in firefox) is to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to temporarily insert a submit button into the form, and click it.  While this does not actually submit the form it does cause the prompt to save to appear, allowing the credentials to be saved and populated next time.

With firefox and firebug extension installed (other browsers have similar extensions or features), right click the userid field and inspect element.  Choose right click the `input` element and choose `edit HTML` in firebug, and insert the following after `class="pagecontents">`:

```
 <input type="submit" name="mysubmit" value="Click!" />
```

It should appear like this:
[image]

Enter your userid and password, taking care **not** to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now hit `Click!` and you should be prompted to save the password.  Save it, reload, and start to enter your password in the userid field and it will be there in the dropdown.  Select it and your password will be automatically populated.

Comment: I deleted my useless comment!  Sorry.